# Does the complex logarithm have a primitive on $\operatorname{Re}z >0$

Tags: integration, logarithms

If $\log:\mathbb{C} \setminus(-\infty,0]\rightarrow \mathbb{C}$ is the principal branch of the complex logarithm, does it then have a primitive on $\{z \in \mathbb{C} : \operatorname{Re}z >0$}?

Can someone help me with this question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, of course: the region is simply connected and the logarithm is holomorphic over it.

An antiderivative is $f(z)=z\log z-z$.